# React Navigation v5: How to get route params of the parent navigator inside the child screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

So I have nested navigators

Main BottomTab.Navigator

- Profile **Bottom Tab # 1** (Stack.Navigator)

  - Profile View (Screen)
  - Followers (Screen)
  - Following (Top Tab.Navigator)

    - Pages (Screen)
    - Groups (Screen)
- Feed **Bottom Tab # 2** (Stack)
- Some other **Bottom Tab # 3** (Stack)

The problem is when I navigate from Profile View Screen to Following Navigator, I pass some parameters to the parent Following Navigator and I want all of those params in the children tabs Screens (Pages/Groups).

But the route of the children tab screens do not get the parameters which are passed to the parent navigator (Following Tab Navigator)

Is there a way to do that?

Here's my code:
**Profile Stack**

```
const ProfileStack = () => (
  <Stack.Navigator
    initialRouteName='profileView'
  >
    <Stack.Screen
      name='profileView'
      component={ProfileScreen}
      options={{
        headerMode: 'screen',
        headerShown: false,
      }}
    />

    <Stack.Screen
      name='followers'
      component={FollowersScreen}
      options={{
        headerTitle: 'Followers',
      }}
    />
    <Stack.Screen
      name='following'
      component={FollowingTabs}
      options={{
        headerTitle: 'Following',
      }}
    />
 </Stack.Navigator>
```

**FollowingTabs**

```
const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
export const FollowingTabs = () => (
  <Tabs.Navigator
    initialRouteName='page'
    lazy
    swipeEnabled
  >
    <Tabs.Screen
      component={PageScreen}
      name='page'
      options={{ tabBarLabel: '2 Pages' }}
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
      component={GroupScreen}
      name='groups'
      options={{ tabBarLabel: '3 Groups' }}
    />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);
```

From the profileView Screen I'm trying to navigate to the following Tabs Screen and need to pass some parameters as follows.

```
const onPressHandler = () => {
    navigation.navigate('following', **{ isPublicProfile, firstName }**);  // These parameters are passed to the route of the following Tabs Navigator
  };
```

And when I try to read these parameters in children tabs (Pages/Groups) these are undefined

```
const PageScreen = ({ route }) => {
  const { isPublicProfile, firstName } = route.params; // undefined?? Can't read parent's params
...
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I found this open Issue on GitHub (https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/43) Is this not possible yet?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So I ended up use `React.Context` as recommended by official React Navigation [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props). Please Follow the official documentation for more information.

> 1- Use React context and wrap the navigator with a context provider to pass data to the screens (recommended).

Here's my solution:

```
const DEFAULT_CONTEXT = {
  isPublicProfile: false,
  ...
};

const FollowingTabNavigatorContext = createContext(DEFAULT_CONTEXT);
```

In Parent Following Tab Navigator

```
const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const FollowingTabs = ({ route }) => {
  const { isPublicProfile } = route.params;
  return (
    <FollowingTabNavigatorContext.Provider value={{ isPublicProfile }}>
      <Tabs.Navigator
        initialRouteName='pages'
        lazy
        swipeEnabled
      >
        <Tabs.Screen
          component={PageScreen}
          name='pages'
          options={{ tabBarLabel: '2 Pages' }}
        />
        <Tabs.Screen
          component={GroupScreen}
          name='groups'
          options={{ tabBarLabel: '3 Groups' }}
        />
      </Tabs.Navigator>
    </FollowingTabNavigatorContext.Provider>
  );
};

FollowingTabs.propTypes = propTypes;
FollowingTabs.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```

And Finally In my the child Tab Screens:

```
export const GroupScreen = () => {
  const { isPublicProfile } = useContext(FollowingTabNavigatorContext);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily use initialParams in tab navigator and pass the props.
Check this solution.

```
<Stack.Screen name="Settings" >
    { (props) => (
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Tab1" component={ Tab1 } 
          initialParams={ props.route.params }  // <- pass params from root navigator
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="Tab2" component={ Tab2 } 
          initialParams={ props.route.params } 
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
      )}
  </Stack.Screen>
```

Reference
https://github.com/react-navigation/rfcs/issues/43#issuecomment-610706264

Comment: This will get overwritten if any of the nested screens need their own parameters. Not an ideal approach

Answer (score 3):

So Here's an alternate hacky solution without using context ;p

BUT Beware this render callback solution comes with a cost. Read [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation/#passing-additional-props)

> Note: By default, React Navigation applies optimizations to screen components to prevent unnecessary renders. Using a render callback removes those optimizations. So if you use a render callback, you'll need to ensure that you use `React.memo` or `React.PureComponent` for your screen components to avoid performance issues.

```
const Tabs = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const FollowingTabs = ({ route }) => {
  const { isPublicProfile } = route.params;
  return (
      <Tabs.Navigator
        initialRouteName='pages'
        lazy
        swipeEnabled
      >
        <Tabs.Screen
          name='pages'
          options={{ tabBarLabel: '2 Pages' }}
        >
          {() => <PageScreen isPublicProfile={isPublicProfile} />}
        </Tabs.Screen>
        <Tabs.Screen
          name='groups'
          options={{ tabBarLabel: '3 Groups' }}
        >
         {() => <GroupScreen isPublicProfile={isPublicProfile} />}
        </Tabs.Screen>
      </Tabs.Navigator>
  );
};

FollowingTabs.propTypes = propTypes;
FollowingTabs.defaultProps = defaultProps;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit!!! : This only works the first time you navigate to the child object. There's probably a way to reset the child or parent every time, but using context is probably better...**

If anyone is still wanting a non-context solution, I believe you can use the `initialParams` prop in the children to do what you're looking for.

Assume route has some params passed to it.

```
export const FollowingTabs = ({route}) => (
  <Tabs.Navigator
    initialRouteName='page'
    lazy
    swipeEnabled
  >
    <Tabs.Screen
      component={PageScreen}
      name='page'
      options={{ tabBarLabel: '2 Pages' }}
      initialParams={route.params // Then you can grab these params using the usual route.params in the PageScreen component} 
    />
    <Tabs.Screen
      component={GroupScreen}
      name='groups'
      options={{ tabBarLabel: '3 Groups' }}
    />
  </Tabs.Navigator>
);
```